# query function with predicate

Tags: f#

Mjello there! I'm at the moment trying to create a F# application, and now I've hit another wall.

The problem lays in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query` module, the `query` function in there wont accept my predicates if they're passed as parameters. Check this out:

```
member x.GetUsersWhere (e:User -> bool) =
    query <@ ctx.Users |> Seq.filter e @>
```

and then I call it like:

```
let service = new UserService()
service.GetUsersWhere (fun z -> z.Name = "James")
```

That should be fine eh? Well, the compiler dosent agree:

> The following construct was used in
>   query but is not recognised by the
>   F#-to-LINQ query translator: Call
>   (None,
>        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User]
>   op_PipeRight[DbSet`1,IEnumerable`1](System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User],
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User]]),
>        [PropertyGet (Some (FieldGet (Some (Value
>   (WebFSharp.Business.UserService)),
>                                      WebFSharp.Business.MyContext ctx)),
>                      System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User]
>   Users,
>                      []),
>         Let (predicate, Value (),
>              Lambda (source,
>                      Call (None,
>                            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User]
>   Filter[User](Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[WebFSharp.Entities.User,System.Boolean],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebFSharp.Entities.User]),
>                            [predicate,
>                             Coerce (source,
>                                     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[WebFSharp.Entities.User,
>   WebFSharp.Entities, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]])])))]) This is
>   not a valid query expression. Check
>   the specification of permitted queries
>   and consider moving some of the query
>   out of the quotation

Whats going on? Is it because the `Expr` will be evaluated before the parameter is injected into it?

Anyway, the following code works but is much less flexible:

```
member x.GetUsersByName name =
    query <@ ctx.Users |> Seq.filter(fun z -> z.Name = name) @>

let service = new UserService()
service.GetUsersByName "James"
```

Could anyone please shed some light on what's happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, the F# to LINQ translator doesn't have any way to examine the function that you specified (the argument `e` is some compiled code - there is no way to get its quoted representation that could be translated to SQL).

You need to use `Expr<User -> bool>` instead of `User -> bool`. This means that instead of passing a function, you'll pass some representation of the code used as argument (which can be analyzed & translated to SQL):

```
member x.GetUsersWhere (e:Expr<User -> bool>) = 
    query <@ ctx.Users |> Seq.filter %e @>
```

Note the `%e` syntax - it means that the quoted code should be embedded (spliced) into the main quoted expression, so the translator sees it as a single expression. When calling it, you need to pass the function using quotations too:

```
let service = new UserService()service.GetUsersWhere <@ fun z -> z.Name = "James" @>
```